# How to avoid unwanted line break after images in Jupter HTML img section?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm trying to format some images in a jupyter notebook. However, linebreaks are being inserted after each image for some reason. What's up with that and how can I avoid it?

```
import io
import base64
from IPython.display import display, HTML

_img = # np array 
_, img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', _img) 
indentation_level = 40  # Number of spaces for indentation
indentation = "-" * indentation_level
image_html = f'<img src="data:image/png;base64,{base64.b64encode(img).decode()}" />'
indented_image_html = f"foo{indentation}{image_html}{image_html}bar"
display(HTML(indented_image_html))
```

[image]

I'm guess its something to do with...

[image]

Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: setting the `style` field in addition to `src` for `img` might work .. however, if you only have the two images, instead of fighting with the CSS, can you append 'em together?